# Duplicated products/pages on a category

Tags: category, duplicate

http://www.pretaplay.co.uk/special-offers.html?p=5

Hi all,

the above link is the beginning of the pages with the issue. Page 5 on this link is duplicated an extra 5 times. Eg page, 6,7,8,9 and 10 feature the same content. On the Sale section.

How would I go about sorting this issue?

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sorting this issue you could go this way.

1. Clear caches & check in private window once.
2. The category page comes from this file
   /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
   **(This is base directory path in your case go to theme directory)**
   Echo something like **echo $_productCollection->count()** & test if the no. of products are same as you added in category.
3. If no success then you have to see & debug the file 
   /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php where pagination comes from.
4. Check if any third party module is used for same. Try to disable it.

**Nice site BTW.**

Comment: Thanks Akhil. Sorted it now, it was the configuration for the front-end product display list. In the backend: System>Catalog>Frontend  -  Basically the wrong number for the products displayed was inputted, was set to 12 instead of 32. Wouldn't of figured it out without you though, so thankyou. :-)